# Undefined Constant when trying to catch an Id in Laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, eloquent

I have a function in Laravel which running this code below

```
$data = AnggotaModel::where([
        ['status_nikah','Menikah'],
        ['jk','Pria']
    ])->get();
```

below is the screenshoot captured from dd($data);

[result of dd($data);](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIP7y.jpg)

What I want is to catch the id so I use this code

```
$id = $data[id];
```

as the result, it ends up with an Error

What should I do to fix this error??

Comment: use this `$id = $data[0][id];`

Comment: it works.. finally.... thank you so much for helping me..

Answer (score 3):

The `get()` method gives you a **collection** of items. Get the **first** element then use  `$data[id]`.
Here you should change it to:

```
$id = $data->first()[id];

// Or in a better way:

$id = $data->first()->id;
```

Comment: it works.. finally.. thank you